# Do I need to write CRC 32 to send craft Ethernet packet by using Packet.Net and SharpPcap

Tags: c#, network-programming, sharppcap, packet.net

I write a code in C# to add MAC header in front of payload and send raw crafted Ethernet Packet by SharpPcap.　I can catch the packet from sender by wireshark, but I cannot receive anything in the receiver end. I find the packet length in the send part is 1514. 
Does it means the FCS error lead all my sent packet are drop by receiver?
Does SharpPcap provide any API to create CRC32?

Comment: it's embarrassing but I have to admit that receiver side have some Intel security client which I haven't notice before... This is firewall things, not sharppcap or packet.net

Comment: NIC will process FCS thing automatically, but sometimes wireshark will show ethernet FCS incorrect which lead me to wrong path